# Problems with DataFrame to generate a table of 15000 rows x 37 columns in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to generate a table with 15000 rows and 16 columns, however Julia loses or omits some variables.

I have tried different ways to run DataFrame but I get the following results:

```
df = DataFrame(periods=15000, households=5000, giniY=giniY)

15,000 rows × 3 columns
```

However, when I run with the 16 variables I get the following result

```
df = DataFrame(periods=15000, households=5000, gamma=gamma, delta=delta,
               betta=betta, alfa=alfa, miz=miz, roz=roz,
               phi=phi, rok=rok, mie=mie, roe=roe,
               roez=roez)

1×13 DataFrame. Omitted printing of 3 columns
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second `df` variable has 13 columns (I have aligned the code in my edit 4 variables per line so that it is clearly visible). Julia omits printing all columns if they would not fit the screen (imagine what would happen if you had a data frame with 10 000 columns and always tried to print them all).

In REPL Julia omits printing columns if they do not fit the screen unless you pass `allcols=true` keyword argument to `show` or create a custom `IOContext` that you pass to `show` that defines a non-standard output width. All this is explained in `show` documentation for `DataFrame`.

In Jupyter Notebook a similar thing happens, but by default the width of the output is governed by `"COLUMNS"` environment variable. The details how you can set it are explained at the beginning of the DataFrames.jl manual [here](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/getting_started/#Installation-1).